# Why onClick() call isn't working inside <img> tag in production?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using images as a clickable links in my React app and the following works nicely
locally (minimal example):

```
const handleAddPostClick = () => {
    console.log('CALLED');
}

return (

<img onClick={() => handleAddPostClick()}
                  name="basics"
                  className="category_btns"
                  style={{ marginLeft: "4px" }}
                  src={isAddPostBtnPressed ? AddPostBtnPressed : AddPostBtn}
                />
  );
```

Strangely enough this doesn't work in production. Can anyone explain please ?

Comment: Is your production build process [stripping out](https://gist.github.com/rupeshtiwari/4bc44953d00670a3980b5e13113d159d#create-bs-module-appwebpackwebpack-optimizationconfigjs) `console.log` calls?

Comment: can you check if your `console.log` is overridden or muted in production ? try using `alert` or `console.warn` or `console.table` and see if it is doing something. There is no reason that this shouldn't work.

Comment: `alert('CALLED');` isn't working either.

Comment: The image suppose to change slightly on click and it stays the same on click thus there is something going on with the onClick() functionality.

Comment: I can see this `js/main.33af1bd4.chunk.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.` in the console but I don't think it has anything to do with it.

Comment: I've noticed `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` in `main.33af1bd4.chunk.js:1` which is one of the files created upon build.